# Autocomplete with few sources (async queries)

Tags: jquery, ajax, facebook, autocomplete

I'm trying to use autocomplete based on few sources. E.g. search in facebook graph and my own db.
It's clear, that facebook search is not so fast as my db. That's why I want to launch few ajax requests for every sorce (each source => separate controller).

After "success" event of request I want to add results autocomplete fields immediately, without any additional actions like typing new letter.

**P.S.** JQuery UI Autocomplete helps not a lot.
Because:

1. Addind images for search results -
   is a plugin.
2. Is possible to set some
   array for search results and add to
   Autocomplete search results, but
   I'll see new results after typing
   new letter.

**P.P.S** As search results I need image, name, 2-3 additional parameters.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: @sdf - Please share some code snippet of what you've done already to let us know what's happening.

Comment: so what's your problem with this?

Comment: @sdf: jQueryUI autocomplete is able to overcome (1) and (2). I believe (1) is possible without a plugin (see the 'custom data and display' demo). (2) you could accomplish by manually triggering events on the autocomplete.

Comment: normaly autocomplete takes results from url and shows it. But I have few resources. And waiting for qype/amazon/facebook sometimes is really long. That's why I want to launch few requests async from client-side with jquery. It's also not a problem. But howto add all results immediately to auctomplete? That user don't need to type something. Problem == rebuild immediatly autocomplete results after achieving request.

Comment: @Andrew Whitaker

1. Is really not a problem.
2. What kind of event? (2) It must be triggered after "open".
Maybe you mean "search"? I'll try now.

Comment: @sdf: Yes, sorry for not being more specific--you could call the `search` method and pass it a value of your choosing.

Comment: Thx, it works. After 5 hours of coding I couldn't do simple rtfm task. Thank you @Andrew Whitaker

Comment: @sdf: No problem! Glad you figured it out.

Comment: @Andrew Whitaker could you duplicate your answer bellow? I want mark it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both **1** and **2** are possible with jQueryUI's autocomplete widget.

1. You can customize the display of the items in the widget by redefining the `_renderItem` method, like in [this example](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data):

   ```
   $("#autocomplete").autocomplete({...})
       .data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
           return $("<li></li>")
               .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
               .append("<a>" + item.label + "<br>" + item.desc + "</a>")
               .appendTo(ul);
       };
   ```
2. You can trigger the autocomplete's [`search`](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-search) method using autocomplete's api:

   ```
   $("#autocomplete").autocomplete("search", "foo");
   ```

Hope that helps! Autocomplete is a surprisingly robust widget and there are tons of questions on StackOverflow that should be able to help if you run into any more problems.

Answer (score 0):

Run some test searches on Facebook before you go too far.  The graph api's search does not return the results you'd get if you used the autocomplete box in Facebook itself.  It's tuned toward searches where the search query is present. I created an autocomplete as you described once, and the results weren't worth it.

I'd love it if they'd make the autocomplete available.